# Is there a way to extract Nintendo 3DS activity log data and to use it in R

Tags: r, logging, nintendo-3ds

I am using unmodded hard- and software (New Nintendo 2DS XL, newest firmware version). Any ideas or example of how it is done (without installing custom firmware)? I sadly could not find anything. I would love to run some data analysis on my old playdata.